# PHP's XMLReader skips subtrees

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I'm trying to parse a large XML file. It looks like:

```
<application>
  <action-keys>
    <case-file>...</case-file>
    <case-file>...</case-file>
    <case-file>...</case-file>
  </action-keys>
  <action-keys>
    <case-file>...</case-file>
    <case-file>...</case-file>
    <case-file>...</case-file>
  </action-keys>
<application>
```

I open it and seek the "case-file" values, but after the first set of case-files, doing a $xml->next("case-file") goes to the end of the file, the second set of case-files are skipped. How to get all the case-files?

Comment: Take a look at SimpleXML - http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: I can't load the whole XML file at a given time.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. It will read all nodes of the files and extract text content of all `case-file` xml element.

```
$caseFiles = array();
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open('content.xml');
while ($xml->read()) {
    if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->name==='case-file') {
        $xml->read();
        $caseFiles[] = $xml->readString();
    }
}
```